# Why fireEvent throws "The given element does not have a value setter" error for antd Select in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, antd

I'm using antd(v3) library in my react app. I have a dropdown to select an option and as well as an input field to pass any values.

```
import {Form, Input, Select, DatePicker} from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item
...
...
<FormItem
            name="apOpCoList"
            label={t('companyNumber')}
            key = {'opco_number'}
            required>
            <Select
                data-testid="ap-opco-selector"
                placeholder={t('placeholder.selectOption')}
                allowClear
                value={apFormValues[apFieldMapping.opCo]}
                onChange={handleOpCoChange}
                >
                {aPOpCos && aPOpCos.map(opCo => <Select.Option
                    key={opCo.companyId}>{opCo.companyName}</Select.Option>)}
            </Select>
        </FormItem>

<FormItem label={t("checkNumber")}
                  name="Check #" key={'check_number'}>
            <Input                value={apFormValues[apFieldMapping.checkNumber]}
                placeholder={`${t(searchMultiplePlaceholderTranslate)} ${t('placeholder.exampleCheckNumber')}`}
                data-testid={apFieldMapping.checkNumber}
                onChange={handleCheckNumberChange}/>
        </FormItem>
```

But, testcase for the input field (ie checkNumber) is passing but select field (ie companyNumber)testcase is failing with error `The given element does not have a value setter`

```
it('should update values when changing the input values', async () => {
const {getByTestId} = renderWithReduxAndThunk(<AP/>, initialState);
  await waitFor(() => {
      const checkNumber = getByTestId(apFieldMapping.checkNumber);
      expect(checkNumber.value).toBe('123456');
  });
})
```

---

```
it('should update values when selecting an OpCo from AP', async () => {
const {getByTestId} = renderWithReduxAndThunk(<AP/>, initialState);
  await waitFor(() => {
    const opcoSelector = getByTestId('ap-opco-selector').querySelector('.ant-select-selection__placeholder');
    fireEvent.change(opcoSelector, { target: { value: '1' } });
    expect(opcoSelector.value).toBe('1');
  });
 })
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: While reading [antd v3 docs](https://3x.ant.design/components/select/) I saw that `Select.Option` must have a `value` prop and this is not present in your code. Perhaps this is the problem. Can you try adding it and give the feedback?

Comment: No, It didn't work either